# File download resuming component for use in Auto Updating

Tags: download, auto-update

It turns out install shield doesn't support file download resuming.

Is there a .net component that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

We use the [AppLife Update component](http://www.kineticjump.com/update/default.aspx). It is specifically for .NET and can resume interrupted downloads and do much more. We found it easy to use and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so,but it's not that hard to write one . There are a lot of **HTTP Clients** already . All that you would need to do is checking to see if the web server actually supports resuming . Check this blog entry for a little info about HTTP and download resuming :

**http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/244.aspx**

All you would need to do is store the number of bytes read so far somewhere ( file , database ) , and read that when you're starting your application again . Be sure to check the md5 for the file ( if it has one ) , to ensure no errors occured .